# Serie numérica rarisima e inexplicable en Java

Tags: java, fibonacci, números-primos

Estimados de stackoverflow:

Soy estudiante iniciando en el maravilloso mundo de la programación Java, pero desde ya tropezando en el camino debido a profesores mediocres y escaso o nula información proporcionado por el libro de estudio,

Pido de favor sugerencias y ayuda para lo siguiente;

Elabore un programa en Java, que permita calcular la sumatoria de los primeros n términos de la siguiente serie numérica:
[image: Serie numérica]

La secuencia del exponente es la que me dificulta realizar.

Tengo el codigo para la serie fibonacci del numerador

Y la serie de primos para el denominador.

Pero no se que lógica ha seguido para elaborar el exponente, lo que veo de manera secuencial es que existe una secuencia aritmetica en el exponente desde el 1 hasta el 8 que va iterando iniciando en el denominador y cambiando entre denominador, el resto es inexplicable para mi, dejo el código que tengo.

```
package evaluacion1bim;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Evaluacion1bim {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    // Declaraciones de variables
    int cantTerminos;   // Cantidad de términos a generar
    int cont;           // Contador de términos generados
    int genNum;         // Número generado para evaluar si es o no primo
    boolean esPrimo;    // Boleano para averiguar si genNum es o no primo 
    int primero;        // Primer sumando del fibonacci
    int segundo;        // Segundo sumando del fibonacci
    int fibo;           // Número fibonacci
    double numerador;   // Númerador de término
    double denominador; // Denominador de término
    double termino;     // Término de la serie
    int contSigno;      // Contador para determinar cuando cambiar de signo
    int signo;          // Signo del término, -1 para negativos y 1 para pos.
    double sumatoria;   // Sumatoria de los términos
    double exponente;   // exponente
    double numerador2;   // Numerador del exponente
    double denominador2;  //Denominador del exponente

    // Objeto del tipo Scanner para interactuar con el teclado
    Scanner lector = new Scanner(System.in);

    // Indicador de entrada
    System.out.print("Ingrese la cantidad de términos a generar: ");

    // Lee la cantidad de términos a generar desde el teclado
    cantTerminos = lector.nextInt();

    // Inicialización de variables
    genNum = 2;
    primero = 0;
    segundo = 1;
    cont = 1;

    fibo = 0;
    signo = -1;
    contSigno = 1;
    sumatoria = 0;
    numerador2 = 0;
    denominador2 = 1;

    // Genera los términos de la serie
    while(cont <= cantTerminos){
      // Incrementa en 1 a genNum
      genNum++;
      System.out.print(genNum +", ");
      // Se asume que genNum es primo
      esPrimo = true;

      // Verifica si genNum es o no primo
      for (int divisor = 2; divisor < genNum ; divisor++) {
        if(genNum % divisor == 0){
          // Si es divisible para otro número diferente de 1 y si mismo
          // el número no es primo
          esPrimo = false;
        }
      }

      if(esPrimo){
        cont++;
        if(esPrimo){
          if(cont > 2){
            fibo = primero + segundo;
            primero = segundo;
            segundo = fibo;

            if(contSigno > 2){
              // Cambia de signo
              signo = signo * -1;
              contSigno = 1;
            }
            contSigno++;
            cont++;
          }
        }
        System.out.println("Sumatoria: " + sumatoria);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Estimados compañeros, de que forma puedo ligar para que cada iteración se genere de manera coordinada toda la serie, eso no se como se podría realizar, muchas gracias por su colaboración, saludos.

Comment: que serie es? no suena a ninguna logica.. que sigue despues de 8/17???

Comment: Así es estimado, es rara, por eso mismo lanzo la pregunta debido a que ustedes me llevan años de ventaja, muchas gracias por su colaboración.

Comment: si no es una serie conocida, no sabria como calcular su valor. Yo creo que deberias volver con quien te dio el problema y y preguntar el nombre de la serie.. podemos conjeturar cosas.. por ejemplo son dos terminos positivos, dos negativos, dos positivos etc.. o que el otro valor del exponente viene en serie 0,2,1(2-1),4(1+3),3(4-1)... pero me matan los dos 8 seguidos al final...

Answer (score 2):

El denominador del exponente extrae en un modo de zig- zag el valor lo hace con la cifra de denominador y numerador principal ... una imagen vale mas que mil palabras, perdona el garabato XD[image: Imagen secuencia]

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu aclaración, entonces el codigo sería igualar el valor del numerador y denomianador principal al secundario , pero y los valores restantes

Comment: los valores restantes del exponente son una serie de números del 1 hasta el 8 según el ejemplo pero me imagino que son tantos como tu quieras, pero ya sabes que aumentan de 1 en 1

Comment: EN efecto ya he encontrado la solucion para esta aberracion llamada serie numerica, paso a describir los componentes;

Comment: En efecto ya he encontrado la solución para esta **cosa** llamada serie numérica, paso a describir los componentes; ya que no puedo dejar un salto de linea; en los numeradores 1 tenemos una serie fibonacci, en en los denominadores es una serie de números primos, en el exponente numerador y denominador se alterna entre una serie aritmética continua y los números del numerador 1 y denominador, se lo comente al profe que estas series violan cualquier formula matemática para determinar un termino cualquiera de la serie solo se limito a decirme que no era clase de matemáticas sino programación

Answer (score 2):

Es un ejercicio de un juez online como [codeforces](http://codeforces.com), con la poca información que se muestra y la secuencia mostrada en la serie pude llegar a esta conclusión:

> El nominador de la base esta descrito por los **N primeros numeros de
>   la secuencia Fibonacci**.
>
> El denominador de la base esta descrito por los **N primeros números
>   primos**.
>
> El nominador y denominador de la potencia esta compuesto por un
>   **ZigZag**, es decir:
>
> **Si la posición de la secuencia es par:** el nominador de la potencia es el nominador de la base. Mientras que el denominador es la posición
>   de la secuencia mas uno.
>
> **Si la posición de la secuencia es impar:** el nominador de la potencia es la posición de la secuencia mas uno. Mientras que el
>   denominador de la potencia es el denominador de la base.

### Solucion en Java

```
class Rextester
{  
    public static void main(String args[]){
        int n = 8;
        System.out.println("\nResultado: " + new Calculo(n).SumarTodo(n));
    }
}

class Calculo {

    private int [] nominadores;
    private int [] expDenominadores;
    private int [] denominadores;
    private int [] expNominadores;

    public Calculo(int n) {

        // Si n es negativo, no puede ser valido
        if(n < 0)
          return;

        // Inicializamos los arreglos
        this.nominadores = new int[n];
        this.expDenominadores = new int[n];
        this.denominadores = new int[n];
        this.expNominadores = new int[n];

        // Llenamos los nominadores con los n primeros numeros de la serie Fibonacci
        for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
          this.nominadores[i] = Fibonacci(i);


        // Llenamos los denominadores con los n primeros numeros primos
        ObtenerPrimos(n);

        // Llenamos la potencia con el ZigZag
        ZigZag(n);

        System.out.print("Nominadores: ");
        ImprimirArreglo(this.nominadores);

        System.out.print("Denominadores: ");
        ImprimirArreglo(this.denominadores);

        System.out.print("Potencia Nominadores: ");
        ImprimirArreglo(this.expNominadores);

        System.out.print("Potencia Denominadores: ");
        ImprimirArreglo(this.expDenominadores);
    }


    // Para las potencias
    private void ZigZag(int n){
        // Calculamos el Zig Zag para obtener los nominadores y denominadores correspondientes
        for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){ 

          // Si la posicion de la fraccion es par
          if(i % 2 == 0){
            // El nominador de la potencia es igual al nominador en la posicion
            this.expNominadores[i] = this.nominadores[i];

            // El denominador de la potencia es igual a la posicion actual mas uno
            this.expDenominadores[i] = (i + 1);
          }

          // Si es impar
          else{

            // El nominador de la potencia es igual a la posicion actual mas uno
            this.expNominadores[i] = (i + 1);
            // El denominador de la potencia es igual al denominador en la posicion
            this.expDenominadores[i] = this.denominadores[i];
          }
        }
    }

    // Para los denominadores
    private void ObtenerPrimos(int n){
        int numero = 1;
        int contador = 0;
        while(contador < n){
          if(esPrimo(numero)){
            this.denominadores[contador] = numero;
            contador++;
          }
          numero += 1;
        }
    }

    private int Fibonacci(int n){

        if(n == 0)
          return 0;
        else if(n == 1)
          return 1;

        return Fibonacci(n-1) + Fibonacci(n-2);
    }

    private boolean esPrimo(int n){

        for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
          if(i == 0 || i == 1)
            continue;
          else{
            if(n % i == 0)
                return false; 
          }
        }

        return true;
    }

    public float SumarTodo(int n){

        if(n < 0)
            return 0f;

        float suma = 0f;
        boolean sumar = true;
        int contador = 1;
        for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
          if(contador < 2)
            contador++;
          else{
            contador = 1;
            sumar = !sumar;
          }
          float base = ((float)this.nominadores[i] / (float)this.denominadores[i]);
          float potencia = ((float)this.expNominadores[i]/ (float)this.expDenominadores[i]);

          if(sumar)
            suma += Math.pow(base, potencia);
          else
            suma -= Math.pow(base, potencia);
        }

        return suma;
    }

    // Imprimimos los arreglos
    public void ImprimirArreglo(int[] arreglo){
        System.out.print("[");
        for(int i = 0; i < arreglo.length; i++){
          if(i + 1 < arreglo.length)
            System.out.print(arreglo[i] + ", ");
          else
            System.out.print(arreglo[i]);
        }
        System.out.println("]");
    }
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Output:**

```
Nominadores: [0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13]
Denominadores: [1, 2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17]
Potencia Nominadores: [0, 2, 1, 4, 3, 6, 8, 8]
Potencia Denominadores: [1, 2, 3, 5, 5, 11, 7, 17]

Resultado: 0.54534584
```

Nota: esto solo funciona para entradas pequeñas <= 30. Si quieres aumentar el input debes utilizar algoritmos eficientes y cambiar el tipo de datos. Por ejemplo `float` a `double` e `int` a `long`. Para obtener los números primos, puedes utilizar [la Criba de Eratostenes](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Criba_de_Erat%C3%B3stenes) y para la serie `Fibonacci` puedes revisar [Estos algoritmos](https://www.nayuki.io/page/fast-fibonacci-algorithms) basados en varios principios o técnicas.